# How to convert a list made up of one tuple into a two item list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a function that returns a one item list, like so:

```
list = [('array_1','array_2')]
```

I want to change this so that the list is instead a two item one, without the parentheses or single quotes:

```
list = [array_1,array_2]
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: `list([('array_1','array_2')][0])`, that would translate the tuple into a list containing both of the entries.

Comment: The first is a tuple of strings, the second is a list containing two variables, where do these come from? There is insufficient information to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 lists = [('array_1','array_2')]
print([y for x in lists for y in x])
```

output

```
['array_1', 'array_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable([('array_1','array_2')]))

['array_1', 'array_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
lst_tuple = [('array_1', 'array_2')]
lst = []
for i in lst_tuple[0]:
    lst.append(i)
```

By iteratating over the list that contains the tuple and appending each item to a new list, you can get this result:

```
['array_1', 'array_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just typecast like this.

```
list = list([('array_1','array_2')][0])
```